# NSIS MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP not shown on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, nsis

I use NSIS to create a Windows installer for one of my projects. The script can be viewed on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/l3u/muckturnier/-/blob/master/res/windows_build/muckturnier_setup.nsi).

I just noticed that the `MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP` image is shown as expected on Windows 7, but not on Windows 10, using the latest version NSIS 3.06.1.

Here's the installer started on Windows 7:

[image: NSIS installer started on Windows 7]

and the very same installer started on Windows 10:

[image: NSIS installer started on Windows 10]

I create the image from an SVG file in the following way:

```
inkscape --export-filename=image.png image.svg
convert image.png BMP2:image.bmp
```

Is this a bug? Or what do I have to change to make the image also appear on Windows 10?

Comment: V3.06 or V3.06.1? Have you tried v3.05?

Comment: Happens both with 3.05 and 3.06.1. Tested with MUI and MUI2. No welcome image on Windows 10 …

Comment: Do you have Windows set to something higher than 96 DPI?

Comment: It's a naked installation in a VM, completely unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after some further investigation, I can answer the question myself.

The problem is apparently the `convert` step. It messes up the image dimensions. Actually, the image has to be (and is) 164 x 314 px. The `convert` output seems to report a size of 20578468 x 1572865 px.

Seems like Windows 7 doesn't care, but Windows 10 does.

Saving the image using the GIMP made it work, using the correct settings: Either an indexed image, with or without RLE encoding or an 8-bit-RGB one. In each case, one has to check "Compatibility Options" → "Do not write color space information".

That's it ;-)

Comment: Your image has the PelsPerMeter members set to a non-zero value. Paint on Windows 10 also does this while Paint on Windows 8 sets it to zero. I don't see why that would prevent it from loading though because it is the standard 40 byte header as far as I can tell.

Comment: Well, however the convert version doesn't show up on Windows 10, and the GIMP version does. So – for whatever reason – it was a format issue I could ship around ;-)